# PL/SQL SELECT on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got two tables. One of these contains userData and the other one contains userGroups linked to users which are in a Group.
Means like a user can be in 0 or more Groups.

I'm trying to get this columns with a query used like this:

```
SELECT distinct(a.userID), a.userName, Count(b.userID_FID)
FORM userData a,
     userGroup b
WHERE a.userID = b.userID_FID
```

But somehow the Count part returning me a wrong number.

Comment: show table data or try `Count(distinct b.userID_FID)`

Comment: are you trying to get the number of groups for each user?

Comment: You need an left outer join for the cases where a user is in zero groups. Is the count wrong or did it just leave out a bunch of users in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT max(a.userName), Count(distinct b.userID_FID)
FROM userData a
JOIN userGroup b
ON a.userID = b.userID_FID
GROUP BY a.userID
```

My suggestion is do not use many tables with from

Comment: I don't think there's a column `userID_FID` in `a` to group on. And besides, if you group on that then your count (per group) is going to always be one.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the number of groups each user is in. 
To build the test scenario, use this:
    create table #groups
    (userID_FID int
    ,groups int
    );

```
create table #user
(userID int);


insert into #groups values (1, 5);
insert into #groups values (1, 2);
insert into #groups values (1, 3);
insert into #groups values (1, 4);

insert into #groups values (2, 3);
insert into #groups values (2, 4);

insert into #groups values (3, 1);
insert into #groups values (3, 5);

insert into #user values (1);
insert into #user values (2);
insert into #user values (3);

select * from #groups;
select * from #user;
```

This piece is the query you want, according to the test scenario above:

```
select userid, count(*) as NumberOfGroups
from #groups g
, #user u
where g.userID_FID = u.userID
group by userID;
```